# Migrating Asp.Net site to Wordpress site

Tags: plugins, migration

I have a requirement to migrate the existing Asp.Net web site to Wordpress site. This site uses SQL server backend. It has so many tables with around 2 million records in a tabular format in SQL server database. I have provided some sample values below,

Ex:

```
+----+-------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| Id | Name  | email   | address  | mobileno | IsActive |
+----+-------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1  | Test  | t@t.com | address1 | 12321321 |     1    |
+----+-------+---------+----------+----------+----------+  

+-------+----------+-------------+-------------+--------------+----------+
| AppId | AppName  | AppAbbrev   | CreateDate  | ModifiedDate | IsActive |
+-------+----------+-------------+-------------+--------------+----------+
| 1     | Test Tool| TT          | 2008-08-18  | 2008-08-18   |     1    |
+-------+----------+-------------+-------------+--------------+----------+  

+------------+--------------+--------------+------------+------------+----------+
| CampaignId | CampaignName | CampaignDesc | StartDate  | EndDate    | CampGroup|
+------------+--------------+--------------+------------+------------+----------+
| 1          | Test Camp    |  Test Camp   | 2008-08-18 | 2008-08-18 |     1    |
+------------+--------------+--------------+------------+------------+----------+

+------------+--------------+--------------+------------+------------+----------+
| RequestId  | RequestName  | RequestDesc  | CustomerId | OrderId    | Status   |
+------------+--------------+--------------+------------+------------+----------+
| 1          | Test Request |  Test Desc   | 2008       | 32423      |     1    |
+------------+--------------+--------------+------------+------------+----------+
```

How to migrate the data into Wordpress database? Is it possible to use the existing database from custom plugin without migrating to WP database because it has around 10 databases with 100 tables?

I googled and found nothing about migrating large number of records from another DB server to Wordpress server.

Comment: Without knowing how your data is structured, it's impossible to answer that question. It's also both too broad and unclear what you are asking. Please read [ask] and file an [edit] to improve your question with the knowledge gained from reading above link. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for pointing out. I updated the question with additional information. Please let me know if you need more information

Comment: Ok, I **edited and reopened** the question. Please understand this as _chance_ to keep it open, as the question still is far from easy to understand and answer worthy. What I edited above is pretty much the output of a raw table query result from a SQL command on the command line. Please log into your machine, connect to your DB (for e.g. `mysql -u {username} -p{password}`), select a database (ex. `show databases; use {databasename};`) and then dump _each and every table_: `select * from {table} limit 0,1` so we can see what you are dealing with. _Remember: D-E-T-A-I-L-S_ :)

Comment: Thanks. I have updated with some more table query results. Please check it. I have around 50 tables inside the database and there are around 10 databases.

Comment: I was just [writing a guide for your](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3933/guide-how-to-add-database-details-to-your-question) :)

Answer (score 2):

**Migrate site from ASP to WordPress**

Now a day WordPress is most popular blogging framework. many people are use WordPress for blogging as well as e-commerce application like online shop. using WordPress you can easily manage SEO, Change contain and take your site backup. WordPress framework is user friendly framework and any one can use without technical knowledge.only need some creativity and all depend on your interest.that’s why most of people prefer WordPress for Dynamic web design.

If you have design your site in to ASP and you want to translate/convert in to WordPress then don’t mind. In this tutorial i will explain how to Migrate site from ASP to WordPress without losing your existing url rank .Some time you have migrate site or convert static to dynamic site it may affect on your rankings. so it important to maintain your ranking.

Although WordPress includes built-in migration tools for importing content from other blogging platforms, migrating an ASP-based site is a little more challenging because everything must be moved manually. After you’ve installed WordPress on your server or with its Web host, you are left essentially with a shell into which you need to insert content. Because all WordPress sites are template-driven, the first thing you must do is select a template. After you’ve selected a template, you can begin migrating your ASP site page by page and then uploading any additional media and other content stored on your company’s server.

**Select a Template**

Step 1 : Log in to your  WordPress dashboard.

Step 2 : Highlight “Appearance” on the main menu and click “Themes” on the menu that appears.

Step 3 : Click the “Install Themes” tab.

Step 4 : Enter search terms into the Search field and place checkmarks in the provided Feature Filter checkboxes to further refine your search criteria. Press the “Search” button or the “Find Themes” button to display a list of themes that match your search criteria.

Step 5 : Browse through the theme thumbnails. Click the “Preview” link below a theme to preview the theme in your browser. Click “Install Now” to download and install the theme on your WordPress site.
If you want to design same layout of  your ASP site then you need to create theme.
You can refer this link for how to create new theme:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Also you need to design different template for different page layout.( like home page template,contact page template,gallery template,single page template) .
Using above link you can design same theme/layout which look like similar to old one.
or you can hire any WordPress developer for create theme.

**Migrate Pages**

Step 1 : Open your ASP website and click one of the items on your site’s main menu.

Step 2 : Launch a second browser tab and log in to your WordPress dashboard.

Step 3 : Hover your mouse over “Pages” on the main menu and click “Add New” on the menu that appears.

Step 4 : Enter a title for your page in the provided field. This title should be the same as the page currently being copied from your ASP site.

Step 5: Highlight all of the text on the current page of your ASP site and click “Ctrl-C” on your keyboard to copy it to the clipboard. Switch back to the tab on which your WordPress dashboard is displayed, click your mouse in the Visual editor and press “Ctrl-V” to paste all of the text into the editor. Some images may copy over, too. If this is the case, click them and delete them because they will be linked to the file directory on your old ASP-based site, rather than to your WordPress site. You will instead need to re-upload these images to your WordPress site from your computer.

Step 6 : Place your cursor at the location in the visual editor where you want an image to appear. Click the “Upload/Insert” button to launch the Add Media dialog. Drag and drop the desired image into the dialog or click “Select Files” and double-click the image from its location on your computer to upload it into your WordPress page. Repeat this step for each image or other multimedia file you want to migrate into this WordPress page.

Step 7 : Click the “Publish” button to finish migrating this page from your ASP site to your WordPress site. Repeat these steps for each page you want to migrate into WordPress.

**Migrate Media and Other Content**

Step 1 : Download the media you want to migrate from your ASP site. Skip this step if the media is already stored on your computer.

Step 2 : Log in to your WordPress Dashboard, highlight “Media” on the main menu and click “Add New” to launch the Add New Media screen. From this screen you can add content to your WordPress library for use at a later date. Compatible content includes videos, images, audio, text files, and more.

Step 3 : Drag and drop your files into the Upload New Media window or click “Select Files” to select files manually. After the files have been uploaded to your WordPress site, you will be prompted to enter titles and descriptions for each file.

**Redirections**

There is a plugin for changing from one permalink structure to another, but I am quite sure that this will not be enough for your needs. You will have to use some .htaccess rewrite rules.

There are several instances when you administer WordPress blogs where you will need to perform a 301 redirect. It is one of the most important corrective actions you can take when moving content.
one reasons why you should do a permanent 301 redirect are to maintain search engine rankings, such as in Google. If you have an old, ranking URL in Google and move to a new, permanent location, a 301 redirect can pass the search engine ranking score of the old ranking URL (not abruptly; it will take time) to the new URL. Hence the new URL will appear and start to rank in the search engine results, replacing the old URL.

If 301 redirection is not implemented, the old URL will still rank in Google. And no matter what you do, your new URL will never appear in search results unless you do a 301 redirect.

Comment: One of the worst tutorials ever...So much of misinformation..